# Vue updates all button text after changing specific button

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

Hi everyone I'm playing around with Vue JS but for some how I cannot get what I expected. Below are my code.

**Template**

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-xs-center" v-for="x in count" :key="x">
      <v-menu offset-y>
        <v-btn
          slot="activator"
          color="primary"
          dark
        >
          {{name}}
        </v-btn>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-tile
            v-for="(item, index) in items"
            :key="index"
            @click="test(item.title)"
          >
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

**Vue**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    name: 'default',
    items: [
      { title: 'Click Me 1' },
      { title: 'Click Me 2' },
      { title: 'Click Me 3' },
      { title: 'Click Me 2' }
    ],
    count: 10
  }),
  methods: {
    test(title) {
      this.name = title
    }
  }
})
```

What I want is that when I change a specific button text the other buttons should not be affected. But it seems my code is doing the opposite. What am I missing here? Any help, explanation would be much appreciated. Thanks

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    name: 'default',
    items: [
      { title: 'Click Me 1' },
      { title: 'Click Me 2' },
      { title: 'Click Me 3' },
      { title: 'Click Me 2' }
    ],
    count: 10
  }),
  methods: {
    test(title) {
      this.name = title
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.3/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.3/dist/vuetify.min.css">


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-xs-center" v-for="x in count" :key="x">
      <v-menu offset-y>
        <v-btn
          slot="activator"
          color="primary"
          dark
        >
          {{name}}
        </v-btn>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-tile
            v-for="(item, index) in items"
            :key="index"
            @click="test(item.title)"
          >
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are iterating over a normal number, in your example 10, so you are just showing 10 times the same variable `name`.
If you now change that variable `name` to something, it will change in all the buttons accordingly.

You need some way to save the different names, e.g. an array of objects like your  `items` with all the titles.

I took your code and changed it a bit. Instead of iterating over a fixed count, I created an array of names and iterate over that array. When you click one of the buttons and change the text, instead of just changing the universal `name` attribute - you change the `name` at the position in the array.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    names: [
{name: 'default 1'}, {name: 'default 2'}, {name: 'default 3'}, {name: 'default 4'}],
    items: [
      { title: 'Click Me 1' },
      { title: 'Click Me 2' },
      { title: 'Click Me 3' },
      { title: 'Click Me 4' }
    ],
  }),
  methods: {
    test(title, index) {
      this.names[index].name = title
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.5.3/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuetify/1.5.3/vuetify.css.map">


<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div class="text-xs-center" v-for="(x, index) in names" :key="'name' + index">
      <v-menu offset-y>
        <v-btn
          slot="activator"
          color="primary"
          dark
        >
          {{x.name}}
        </v-btn>
        <v-list>
          <v-list-tile
            v-for="(item, i) in items"
            :key="'item' + i"
            @click="test(item.title, index)"
          >
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
      </v-menu>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```